# Children Shortcodes?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, children

I started creating WordPress plugins a few weeks ago, and I would like to know if it's possible to somehow "embed" shortcodes in some others. Basically what I want to do is create a table or a list, based on a set of items entered by the user of the plugin. Is it possible to have something like :

```
 [data]
    [item1] something [/item1]
    [item2] something else[/item2]
    [item3] something else[/item3]
 [/data]
```

In short, I want to create something based on the elements contained in the *itemX* "children" shortcodes. Is there any way to do something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but you can only nest one level down, after that the shortcode regexp parser flips out. So your example would be okay, but [item1] would not be able to contain even more nested shortcodes.

To enable nesting, just go ahead and do:

```
add_shortcode('data', function($attributes, $content='')
{
    return do_shortcode($content);
}
```

Relevant article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-nested-shortcodes/